# Persist an implementation which has no properties

Tags: java, jpa, entity

Given the following classes and interface I am wondering how JPa handles it:

```
public interface Operator{
    public String getOperator();
}
```

Let's stay I then have two implementations of this class:

```
public class PlusOperation implements Operator, Serializable {
    public String getOperator(){
        return "+";
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class MinusOperation implements Operator, Serializable {
    public String getOperator(){
        return "-";
    }
}
```

There exists a class marked as `@Entity` which has a property `Operator`:

```
@Entity
public class Function {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private Operator operator;
    // Other methods & properties omitted for clarity
}
```

In the Function class therefore, it could hold either a `PlusOperation` or `MinusOperation` and neither of these classes have been annotated with `@Entity` as they don't have any properties that require persisting but they each are different. How does JPA handle this? When persisting a `Function` object does it automatically (and 'behind the scenes') mark the `operator` property with the correct `Operation` implementation?

Comment: An entity is a way of storing **data**. Not a way of storing behaviour. This is a complete abuse of ORM. Don't.

Comment: That would not work anyway, since the only way to persist the operator is by serializing it, and it's not Serializable.

Comment: Boris, I agree but that's what I have got to work with so the question still remains. Also JB Nizet I have implemented the Serializable inteface.

Comment: Just read the documentation in that case. This is dependant on the type of inheritance pattern, but essentially the specific subclass is stored in a table and the correct type created. Read, for example, the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a JPA AttributeConverter that stores the "operator" field as a String or Integer. That way it doesn't matter one iota whether this other type (which isn't an Entity) doesn't have any properties of its own. You converter is then responsible for deciding what is persisted, and how it is retrieved.